# Awslogs log driver vs AWS Firelens - which one to use and when and cost factor

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, firelens

I am planning to migrate our app to AWS Fargate and so want to set up logging for the same as well and store all the logs in cloudwatch. I could see we have two options in Fargate - either use default `awslogs` log driver or use `AWS Firelens` to gather logs. I read the AWS documentation but unfortunately still not able to figure out which option to use and when precisely. Also, can someone advise on the cost side as well- which option costs how much between using awslogs driver vs aws firelens to send logs to cloudwatch in the same account? [I am looking for easy and efficient and cost effective option]

Is it fair to say in general,we use AWS Firelnes when you want to send logs data to non-AWS tools like elastic stack or datadog etc **vs** use awslogs driver when sending logs to cloudwatch
Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Fargate launch type and want to use `CloudWatch`: You have to use awslog driver in your task definition. You can find more information about the `CloudWatch` pricing [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/). CloudWatch has a free tier and anything after the free tier cap (metrics, dashboards, alarms, logs, events, etc) has a different pricing calculation. For example, first 10K metrics cost 0.3$ in most regions, but the next 240K will cost 0.1$ while events are priced at 1$ for 1 million

Using Fargate and don't want to use `CloudWatch`: Use AWS FireLens to push container logs to third party logstorage system. The cost of 3rd party log storage system would come in play here. Data Dog/AppDynamics and others usually offer membership packages (Free/Premium/Enterprise etc). Unlike CloudWatch, each package will give you different capabilities. For example, on the free tier in DataDog you do not have alerts. Also non-AWS native monitoring tools are priced per host/CPU core for a specific amount of hours.

Firelens would also make sense if you want to ship to `CloudWatch` but want to do upfront filtering versus sending everything to `CloudWatch`

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want all the log output from your ECS Fargate tasks to go to AWS CloudWatch Logs, then use the `awslogs` driver. This basically works "out of the box" with no further configuration needed on your part. This is the easiest solution. The only additional cost will be the cost of CloudWatch Logs, detailed in the "Logs" tab [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/).

If you want to send logs to some other logging service, like Splunk, then use the Firelens driver, and provide a Firelens configuration file that tells Firelens where to send your logs. There is no added cost for using the Firelens driver, but of course there is the added cost of whatever target services you configure Firelens to send your logs to.